# Removing a row does not change change output of length() and levels()

Tags: r, row

Using below code I import a dataset, explore it and remove a row. 
After removing the row the output of my length and levels command is unchanged. Why?

```
MT <- read_csv("Q:/PhD/PhD courses/Data Doc and Man/day3-day4/bromraw.txt", 
    col_names = FALSE)
names(MT) <- c("id","pnr","age","sex", "runtime")
MT$sex <- as.factor(MT$sex)
length(levels(MT$sex))
levels(MT$sex)
```

This is the output:

[1] 3

[1] "33529" "K"     "M"

Something is wrong. I investigate the row where sex has the value 33529

```
filter(MT, sex == 33529)
```

After examining the row I decide to drop it, and recheck the sex variable again.

```
MT <- subset(MT, sex !=33529)
length(levels(MT$sex))
levels(MT$sex)
```

[1] 3

[1] "33529" "K"     "M"

The row is not there when I browse the data, but the output of the length and levels command is the same as before. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel the question deserves a better explanation than just a piece of code.

Factor levels can exist independent of the data, e.g.

```
x <- factor(character(0), levels = LETTERS[1:3])
```

creates a vector of length 0 which has 3 factor levels

```
x
```

> ```
> factor(0)
> Levels: A B C
> ```

The length of the vector `length(x)` is zero but `x` has 3 levels

```
levels(x)
```

> ```
> [1] "A" "B" "C"
> ```

(and `length(levels(x))` is 3, accordingly).

The benefit is that we can add data later on which is checked if it is compatible with the defined factor levels:

```
x[1:4] <- LETTERS[1:4]
```

> Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 1:4, value = c("A", "B",
>   "C", "D")) :   invalid factor level, NA generated

```
x
```

> ```
> [1] A    B    C    <NA>
> Levels: A B C
> ```

Now, the vector consists of 4 elements (`length(x)`) but there are still only 3 factor levels. Note that `"D"` has not become an additional factor level automatically but was replaced by `NA` instead.

If elements of the vector are removed, e.g.

```
y <- x[-c(1L, 4L)]
y
```

> ```
> [1] B C
> Levels: A B C
> ```

the factor levels remain unchanged while `length(y)` is 2 now.

However, if you want to remove unused factor levels you can do so by explicitely using the `droplevels()` function [as pointed out by akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46477659/3817004):

```
y <- droplevels(y)
y
```

> ```
> [1] B C
> Levels: B C
> ```

Now, factor level `"A"` has been dropped as it is unused.

---

While the `levels()` function shows the factor levels which are defined it does not tell which of the *boxes* (credit to [Acccumulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46477616/removing-a-row-does-not-change-change-output-of-length-and-levels/46493988?noredirect=1#comment79943383_46493988) for the picture) are filled or not. The `unique()` function returns a vector of distinct values while the `table()` function counts the number of occurrences:

```
set.seed(1L)
z <- sample(LETTERS[1:8], 10, replace = TRUE)
z
```

> ```
> [1] "C" "B" "E" "H" "A" "B" "D" "A" "D" "C"
> ```

```
unique(z)
```

> ```
> [1] "C" "B" "E" "H" "A" "D"
> ```

```
table(z)
```

> ```
> z
> A B C D E H 
> 2 2 2 2 1 1
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much for this very detailed answer. I see now that I have misunderstood what levels() actually does. I thought it returned an overview of the levels in use for a given variable. 
Can you tell me if there is another command than levels() which will return the levels in use for a given variable?
Something similar to "codebook" in STATA

Comment: `unique(MT$sex)` will give a vector of distinct values while `table(MT$sex)` will count the number of occurrences.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is very appreciated.

Comment: But it *is* an overview of the levels in use. Just because no elements take a level, doesn't mean the level isn't in use. Metaphorically, each level is a box that elements can be put in. "levels()" returns a list of all the boxes. Just because a box is empty, doesn't mean it's not there. And as far as r knows, the box is still in use; you *could* put something into it at any moment. When you take all the dishes out of the dishwasher, do you throw the dishwasher away, or do you keep it around in case you want to put something else in it?

Comment: @Acccumulation Comparing factor levels with boxes is an excellent and vivid picture!

Answer (score 2):

This could be a case of unused levels.  We can resolve it by dropping the levels

```
MT <- droplevels(subset(MT, sex != 33529))
```

Comment: Thank you. This command fixed it.
I am a bit perplexed as to what the levels()  command actually does. I thought it was summary of the levels used in variable, but I can see now that it is not. Do you know of any command that tells returns what levels are actually being used?

Comment: @SteenHarsted Imagine that you are building some model with training/test dataset and have factor class.  If the unused levels gets dropped out in the test dataset, then it may complain about missing levels.  There are also other cases where it is better not to drop the levels